# Name for relationship where one graph is a minor usually implies another is?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, terminology, graph-minor

Let $G$ and $H$ be graphs with the following relationship: for some $k$, after you perform at least $k$ arbitrary subdivisions of the edges of $G$ (or the edges produced through subdivision), $H$ must be a minor. What do you call the relationship between $G$ and $H$?

For example, consider a claw with each edge subdivided once and a claw with one edge subdivided twice. You can subdivide any edge of the former to produce a graph for which the latter is a minor $(k = 1)$. Is anyone writing about this or has it been given a name?

Comment: Are you sure you are stating this correctly?  Isn't the first paragraph simply "$H$ is a minor of $G$"?  Why not add a bunch of isolated vertices, making $k$ irrelevant?

Comment: Are you looking for [topological minor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28graph_theory%29#Topological_minors)?

Comment: @Andrew: you're right, the first paragraph does have a misstatement. I'll edit.

Comment: Is this a correct way to rephrase the relationship you want to describe: "H is a minor of almost all subdivisions of G," where "almost all" means "all but finitely many."

Comment: @Robin, I think the condition is weaker: after fixing some $k$, after he construct the upward set, he's requiring that $H$ be a minor, for all such sets.

Comment: @Suresh: Do you mean the relationship is parametrized by k? Like "H is a minor of every k-subdivision of G"? Where a k-subdivision of G is any graph obtained from G after k elementary subdivisions. It sounded to me like the relationship described only required the existence of such a k. @Eli: What is the correct interpretation of your question?

Comment: I have never heard of this, but I believe it is equivalent to saying that if you subdivide any edge of $G$ $k$ times, $H$ will then be a minor.

Comment: @Robin, I believe so, with "k" replaced by "at most k"

Comment: Andrew is correct in what I intend.